# BASH: normalize list columns - replicate row for each item in a list

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix

I would like to to create a separate row for each item separated by comma in BASH

For example, to convert this table:

```
TYPE  NAME  
Fruit  apple,strawberry
Vegetable  potato
```

Into this table:

```
TYPE  NAME  
Fruit  apple
Fruit  strawberry
Vegetable  potato
```

I have tried this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define the name of the input file
input_file="plants.tsv"

# define the name of the output file
output_file="normalized_plants.tsv"

# define the index of the list column (counting from 1)
list_column=2

# create a new file with the headers for the output table
head -n 1 "$input_file" > "$output_file"

# read each line of the input file
tail -n +2 "$input_file" | while IFS=$'\t' read -r line; do
  # extract the values for the list column
  list_values=$(echo "$line" | awk -F$'\t' '{print $'"$list_column"'}' | tr ',' '\n')
  # iterate over each value in the list column
  echo "$line" | awk -F$'\t' -v OFS=$'\t' -v list_column="$list_column" -v list_values="$list_values" '
    NR == 1 { next } # skip the header row
    { 
      split(list_values, values, "\n")
      for (i in values) {
        $list_column = values[i]
        print $0
      }
    }' >> "$output_file"
done
```

But what I get in return is an empty output file. Do you have any idea what went wrong here, or maybe some better solution to achieve this? I am the beginner in BASH and this might not be the best way to achieve normalization.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a shell read loop for this, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice), just a single awk script will run orders of magnitude faster, be more portable, and be easier to write robustly (for example - you currently have 2 answers using shell read loops, both would will fail if a "type" contained a blank and one of them would also fail if the input contained any backslashes), e.g. using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# define the name of the input file
input_file="plants.tsv"

# define the name of the output file
output_file="normalized_plants.tsv"

# define the index of the list column (counting from 1)
list_column=2

awk -v list_column="$list_column" '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    {
        n = split($list_column,names,",")
        for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
            print $1, names[i]
        }
    }
' "$input_file" > "$output_file"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
```

```
$ cat normalized_plants.tsv
TYPE    NAME
Fruit   apple
Fruit   strawberry
Vegetable       potato
```

I'm using `for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ )` instead of `for ( i in names )` above to guarantee that the order of names from the input is retained in the output, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array.

Comment: Thank you!!! I understand the solution, it's way better and clearer.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is just to inform you that your script using pure `bash` can be condensed to:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r type names; do
    echo "$type"$'\t'"${names//,/$'\n'$type$'\t'}"
done < plants.tsv > normalized_plants.tsv
```

Normally, the `awk` solution should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`:

```
while read type name_list; do                # Read the 2 fields in type and name_list
    readarray -d, -t names <<< "$name_list," # Split the name_list by comma and save it in names array.
    unset names[-1]                          # This line is only to remove the tailing newline for the last entry.
    for name in "${names[@]}"; do            # For each name, ...
        echo "$type $name"                   # ... print type and name
    done
done < plants.tsv > output_plants.tsv        # Input, output file redirection.
```

`awk` version:

```
awk '{split($2, s, ","); for(i in s){print $1, s[i]}}' plants.tsv > output_plants.tsv
```

Comment: thank you @anishsane! I just have one question, in the awk version, what I want to split more than one column, for example I want to split second and third, can I simply write split($2, $3, s, ",") or is there some other way?

Comment: You can check the [split function in awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-split_0028_0029-function-1). I cannot write long comment here. The man page has examples and syntax. But TBH, I did not understand your question in the comment. Do you want to split $2+$3 concatenation? If yes, then Just writing `$2 $3` (without any symbol in them) will concatenate it and then use `split($2$3, s, ",");`. Else, `split($2, s2, ",");`, `split($3, s3, ",");`

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety, a simple string processing solution with `sed`.

```
$: sed -E ':x ; s/^([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+([^,]+),/\1\t\2\n\1\t/; t;' file
TYPE  NAME
Fruit   apple
Fruit   strawberry
Vegetable  potato
```

Works with the simple file given. Make sure you confirm anything more complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '
TYPE  NAME  
Fruit  apple,strawberry,banana
Vegetable  potato' |
```

> ```
> mawk 'NR==!_ || $NF!~/,/ || gsub(",[^,]+", "\n"$!_ " &", $NF) + gsub(",",_)'
> ```

```
TYPE  NAME  
Fruit apple
Fruit strawberry
Fruit banana
Vegetable  potato
```

if you wanna be pedanic about the output separation gap, then

> ```
> gawk 'NR==!_ ? OFS = substr($_, match($_, "[ \t]+"),RLENGTH) \
>              : $NF!~/,/ || gsub(",[^,]+", "\n" $!_ OFS "&", $NF) gsub(",",_)'
> ```

```
TYPE  NAME  
Fruit  apple
Fruit  strawberry
Fruit  banana
Vegetable  potato
```